# customers who have ordered more than once between 2001 and 2012. Of this list, we need the segment of customers who have not ordered after 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have Orderdetails Table. In this table, I have customers who have ordered more than once between 2001 and 2012.

In this list I need the segment of customers who have not ordered after 2012.

I wrote this query:

```
select distinct CustomerEmail, orderdate 
from orderdetails    
where OrderDate between Convert(varchar(50),'01/01/2001',101) 
    and Convert(varchar(50),'12/31/2012',101) 
    and customeremail not in (
        select distinct CustomerEmail 
        from orderdetails     
        where OrderDate between Convert(varchar(50),'01/01/2012',101) 
            and Convert(varchar(50),'10/31/2014',101) 
    ) 
    and TransactionId is null
```

Comment: Is there something else wrong with your query than just the convert varchar parts?

Comment: To improve it, you should use "and not exists (select.." instead of "customeremail not in ..."

Answer (score 0):

The following should get what you need. Obviously replace "Customer" with you're customer identifier.

```
select distinct CustomerEmail, orderdate from orderdetails 
where customer NOT IN (
select customer from orderdetails where orderdate between '20120101' and '20140101'
```

This has been done on the assumption you are using sql server, it does say about 3 RDBMS systems in the tags though.

**TIP**

Try and avoid casting/converting dates in the where clause, it can have serious effects on performance

Comment: Its not working i have lacks of customers in my table.. I want who have not ordered after 20012 to 2014

Comment: @SushmaSatya I've made an edit, try again. Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft’s SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the HAVING ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms180199.aspx)) clause?  It allows you to perform a WHERE like function on an aggregated column.

This example returns all merchants where the most recent order year does not fall between 2012 and 2014.

I've used a CTE here, as I don't have the same tables available to me.  However the principle from the SELECT statement, at the bottom of the query, is all that really matters here:

```
/* This query should return from OrderDetail
 * customers who have not ordered between 2012
 * and 2014.
 * Only customer A no orders in this window.
 */
WITH OrderDetail AS
    (
        /* Sample order detail table.
         * Customer A has orders in 2001 & 2011.
         * Customer B has orders in 2013, only.
         */
        SELECT
            r.CustomerId,
            r.OrderDate,
            r.OrderValue
        FROM    
        (
            VALUES
                ('A', '2001-01-01', 10.10),
                ('A', '2001-02-03', 25.17),
                ('A', '2011-11-25', 10.22),
                ('B', '2013-01-07', 37.50)
        ) AS r(CustomerId, OrderDate, OrderValue)
)
-- ********************************************************
-- You can ignore the common table expresssion (CTE) above.
-- I've only included it so you can see/change the sample 
-- data.  This should make testing easier.
-- ********************************************************
SELECT
    CustomerId,
    MIN(OrderDate)        AS FirstOrderPlaced,
    MAX(OrderDate)        AS LastOrderPlaced,
    COUNT(*)            AS OrdersPlaced,
    SUM(OrderValue)        AS LifetimeOrderValue
FROM
    OrderDetail
GROUP BY
    CustomerId
HAVING
    YEAR(MAX(OrderDate)) NOT BETWEEN 2012 AND 2014
;
```